# Excel Password Breaker crashing the program

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm working on an Excel file that has about a dozen separate sheets. I used the code below to break the password on each of the sheets.

However, there are two sheets where I'm running into a problem. Each time I run the code below, it completely crashes Excel. I've tried various different codes to break the password on these two sheets, but the same issue continues to occur.

These two sheets don't seem to have any differences to the other sheets, but maybe I'm overlooking something? The workbook is not protected, and there aren't any other Macros within the file. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

```
Sub PasswordBreaker()
 'Breaks worksheet password protection.
 Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
 Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
 Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
 Dim i4 As Integer, i5 As Integer, i6 As Integer
 On Error Resume Next
 For i = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
 For l = 65 To 66: For m = 65 To 66: For i1 = 65 To 66
 For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66: For i4 = 65 To 66
 For i5 = 65 To 66: For i6 = 65 To 66: For n = 32 To 126
 ActiveSheet.Unprotect Chr(i) & Chr(j) & Chr(k) & _
 Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & _
 Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
 If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
 MsgBox "One usable password is " & Chr(i) & Chr(j) & _
 Chr(k) & Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & _
 Chr(i3) & Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
 Exit Sub
 End If
 Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
 Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: maybe you can try to export those sheets to a new workbook and run the code there.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and still ran into the same problem. But I then saved this separate workbook as an older version of Excel (97 -03), and was able to run the code properly! Thank you Mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I exported the two sheets into a new workbook, and then saved the workbook as an older version (97 - 03). This allowed me to run the macro successfully!

I simply just copied these two sheets back over to the original file.